# Clear all the tables of particular DB

Tags: rethinkdb

is there any query available for rethinkDB to clear all the **tables** of specific **DB**?

we can delete one by one table by running `.delete()`

Answer (score 2):

```
r.db('DB_NAME').tableList().forEach(function(t){
  return r.db('DB_NAME').table(t).delete()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure functional approach based on @taygetos answer

```
(db => r.db(db).tableList().forEach(t => r.db(db).table(t).delete()))('My_database');
```